# vuematerial - trigger md-tabs with code

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-material

I am using `[md-tabs][1]` from `vue-material` in my new project.

I understand we use `@md-changed` event with `js` function:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
<md-tabs class="md-primary" :md-active-tab="currenttab" @md-changed="tabChanged">
<md-tab id="tab-users" md-label="Users">
...
</md-tab>
<md-tab id="tab-projects" md-label="Projects">
...
</md-tab>
</md-tabs>
</div>
</template>

<script>
...
methods: {
      tabChanged: function(id) {
        console.log(id);
      },
}
...
</script>
```

But how can I create a function to trigger md-tab change?

there is a `props` `md-active-tab` with description:

> Set the current selected tab. Works by providing the id of the desired
>   md-tab.

so I have a button with `js` function:

```
activateTab: function(id) {
        console.log(id);
        self.currenttab = id;
      }
```

which `currenttab` is bind with:

```
<md-tabs class="md-primary" :md-active-tab="currenttab" @md-changed="tabChanged">
```

but when i click the button, the function works(console.log is showing) but the tab did not go to the assigned tab.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what is `self` variable in `activateTab` fn? is it typo? how do you use `activateTab` function?

Comment: You spot my mistake! I have to declare `var self=this;` so that `self.currenttab = id;` will work.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resolve efficiently, so that , I have workaround by below.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".md-tabs > div > button")[_index].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

A very basic mistake pointed out by @Max Sinev.

I need to have declare `self` in the function:

```
activateTab: function(id) {
        var self = this;// <-- declare self
        console.log(id);
        self.currenttab = id;
      }
```

with that, I can trigger the tab change with function.